# How to type the number of combinations with repetitions?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

For the number of [combinations with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Combination&oldid=667401898#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) a symbol similar to the binomial coefficient is used with additional parentheses:

[image]

What would be the proper way how to type the symbol in LaTeX? I was thinking of adding `\left(` and `\right)` to `{n\choose k}`, but it doesn't seem right.

Update: Also I'd be interested how to type it in MathJax, if possible.

Comment: in the wikipedia link, it's written by `\left(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\!\right)`...

Comment: This could be work for a displayed math content: `\newcommand{\mybinom}[2]{\left(\mkern -10mu \binom{#1}{#2}\mkern -10mu \right)}` but for sure does not work on inline.

Comment: the question cited by @Kiraa definitely addresses the same problem, but the answers given there would be better with a visual.  (i'm not in a position to edit that in though.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Visual added...